How do I make a iframe adjust to the height of the content when the content is a PDF?
I have a iframe,but I want to integrate it into the website with no scroll bar, so the size should be the size of the content.
There are many questions about IFrames and making their size equal to their content's size, but none of the solutions to those questions seem to work in my case.
I tried using
View.js
function resizeIframe(frame) {
    frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px'
}

View.html
        <iframe src="{{source}}" onload="resizeIframe(this)">

        </iframe>

But, all of my content is in PDF files, and frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight is 0.
Other questions show how to make the frame adjust to content, but their example works for html content, my content is all PDF.
Is there anyway to get the height of my embed PDF?

I doubt this will be possible. Browsers showing PDFs "natively" like that, still create some basic HTML structure around this first - but that differs from browser to browser. And if I inspect the DOM in Chrome for example, it is all elements with the same dimensions as the iframe, down the the embed element that actually eventually embeds the PDF. Even the scrollHeight property of that element is the same as the iframe's height.

If you know the dimensions of your PDF upfront, you could stick it into an iframe that keeps the same aspect ratio. (But that might not work any more then, if the user switches the display mode of the PDF.)

This can be done by combining pdf.js and iframe-resizer.
